# Python Import Error from rospack

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi peeps,

I'm following along with the ROS tutorials ([Creating a Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)) and when I run

`rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`

I get this error

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 36, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .manifest import InvalidManifest, Manifest, parse_manifest_file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 40, in <module>
    import xml.dom.minidom as dom
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 22, in <module>
    from xml.dom.xmlbuilder import DOMImplementationLS, DocumentLS
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.py", line 3, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 36, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .manifest import InvalidManifest, Manifest, parse_manifest_file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 40, in <module>
    import xml.dom.minidom as dom
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 22, in <module>
    from xml.dom.xmlbuilder import DOMImplementationLS, DocumentLS
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.py", line 3, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/home/dev/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
```

I have a miniconda environment configured and I verified that rospack is indeed using the correct interpreter (Edited the /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/init.py file to print sys.executable). I can import these modules

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:04:19) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rosdep2 import rospack
>>> import weakref
>>> from _weakref import _remove_dead_weakref
>>>
```

Python Interpreter

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ which python
/home/dev/miniconda2/bin/python
```

Pip

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ which pip
/home/dev/miniconda2/bin/pip
```

Located rosdep2

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ locate rosdep2
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/_version.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_packages.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_support.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_support.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/core.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/core.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/dependency_graph.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/dependency_graph.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/loader.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/loader.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/model.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/model.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rep3.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rep3.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospkg_loader.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospkg_loader.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/shell_utils.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/shell_utils.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/arch.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/arch.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/cygwin.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/cygwin.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/freebsd.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/freebsd.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/gem.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/gem.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/gentoo.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/gentoo.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/opensuse.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/opensuse.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/osx.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/osx.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/pip.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/pip.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/redhat.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/redhat.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/slackware.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/slackware.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/source.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/source.pyc
```

Python Path

```
dev@dev-test-eth1:~/catkin_ws/src$ echo $PYTHONPATH 
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Some additional info

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Kinetic ROS dist
- miniconda2 py2.7

I heard on this [original ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1697) that miniconda2 is not a supported python environment (I'd have to build from source), I'm not locked in to miniconda2 but I cannot remove it from my system, and ideally I wouldn't remove the path either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320995/python-import-error-from-rospack/) by [maspe36](https://answers.ros.org/users/40857/maspe36/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For now I was able to get past this step by simply removing the miniconda2 python from my path var. So perhaps you will need to do a conda install for packages instead of pip?

---

Originally posted by [maspe36](https://answers.ros.org/users/40857/maspe36/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0